# Why extra parenthesis is needed to compile "std::thread" functor?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm moving from "ancient" c++ to the newer C++ 11 and looking into the `std::thread` library.

```
class MyThread
{
public:
    int i = 0;
    void operator()()
    {
        for (;i < 10000; i++)
            cout << "Exectuing " << endl;
    }
};
```

In `main()` I have the following lines:

```
thread threadObj( MyThread() );

for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    cout << "Main thread " << endl;

threadObj.join();
```

It won't compile the last line : "Expression must have a class type"

Adding extra parenthesis to  `thread threadObj( (MyThread()) );` solves the problem.

Why ? The type remains the same : `thread`.

Am I missing some new c++ 11 feature ? or am I just confused...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you see is known as most vexing parse: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

For that reason from c++11 you can use the new '{}' for initialization.

With new form you can write:

```
thread threadObj{ MyThread{} };
```

This creates `MyThread` with an empty initializer list and the thread object itself with the object which was created before with the `MyThread{}` initialization.

What is going on by using the form: `thread threadObj( MyThread() );` ?
The compiler interprets it as a function call and not as initialzation of an object. So using the new `{}` form makes that clear for the compiler.

If you use `{}` in your program, you should use it stringent. Using it like:

```
thread threadObj{ MyThread() }; // bad style!
```

looks a bit mysterious, because you use in one line the old and the new version. That technically works, but makes code unreadable. ( at least for my eyes :-) )

Answer (score 0):

> > Am I missing some new c++ 11 feature ? or just confused.

yes, in c++11, you use universal initializers. change the line of code

```
thread threadObj( MyThread() );
```

as

```
 thread threadObj{ MyThread() };
```

it will work fine

Comment: Can you elaborate ? why `thread threadObj( (MyThread()) );` does work ? and otherwise doesn't ?